# changing db value in input form in reframe

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

I've been trouble by an updating issue in `reframe`.

db.cljs:

```
{:apple 16}
```

event.cljs

```
(rf/reg-event-db
:update-apple-size
  (fn [ db [_ size] ]
    (assoc db :apple size)))
```

subs.cljs

```
(rf/reg-subs
 ::apple-size
 (fn [ db ]
    (get db :apple)))
```

views.cljs

```
[:input {:type :text
         :on-change (rf/dispatch [:update-apple-size (.. % -target -value js/parseFloat))]
         :value @(rf/subscribe [::apple-size] }]
```

The issue happed when user udpating with decimal number of the size. When user try to update current `16` to `16.5`.

User will strike `.` ,but this will be trigger `on-change` event and *wont'* update the db value. ( {:apple 16} => {:apple 16.0} ) ?. Then the subscribe will render "16.0" to UI as "16" ?

that's why user can't really append decimals after an integer in `input` element ?

- one way I can think of is stringyfy all values in `db` but this will create lots of trouble since there are lots of calculation assuming the values are number in the db.

Any advise will be helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `js/parseFloat` parses a string with a decimal dot into an integer:

```
cljs.user=> (js/parseFloat "16.")
16
```

One solution can be to save into `db` two values:

- the value of `input` as a string
- the parsed value of `input`

Then `input` will display a string with a decimal dot. See example:

Db:

```
(def default-db
  {:input-val "5"
   :input-num 5})
```

Views:

```
 [:input {:type "string"
                     :value @(re-frame/subscribe [::subs/input-val])
                     :on-change #(re-frame.core/dispatch [:change-val (-> % .-target .-value)])}]
            [:div
             [:p @(re-frame/subscribe [::subs/input-num])]]
```

Subs:

```
(re-frame/reg-sub
  ::input-val
  (fn [db] (:input-val db)))

(re-frame/reg-sub
  ::input-num
  (fn [db] (:input-num db)))
```

Events:

```
(re-frame/reg-event-db
  :change-val
  (fn [db [_ val]]
      (-> db
          (assoc :input-val val)
          (assoc :input-num (js/parseFloat val)))))
```

Comment: that woud almost double the `db` but the answer is great that it inspire me to use 
`(.toFix (js/parseFloat "16.") 2)` ... will almost fix the issue.. this will put a float in the `db` even though it was really wired input style for user.